# Playing AVI, WMV, SWF on a website, with single player

Tags: flash, avi, wmv

I've been looking for a player to support multiple formats, the ones in the title for example, or several that I could use to play them, but I've had no luck, has anyone actually developed one for all formats? Or does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give a use case, so I'm not sure if you really need AVI playback, but in general, the way going forward for video on the web is [HTML5 video](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html). [Mark Pilgrim's Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) has a great rundown of the topic and I'd recommend [Video for Everyone](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) as a specific implementation.